# Kotlin Multiplatform not Support Lower API 24?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, android-api-levels

I use android studio and emulator with android API 22 Lollipop 5.1

I want to start a new project with KMM but can't start the emulator

```
android {
compileSdkVersion(29)
defaultConfig {
    applicationId = "com.mcic.salon.myapplication2.androidApp"
    minSdkVersion(24)
    targetSdkVersion(29)
    versionCode = 1
    versionName = "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    getByName("release") {
        isMinifyEnabled = false
    }
}
```

Meaning can't make an application for android 5 by KMM?

Comment: Not being able to start the emulator has nothing to do with it being a KMM project

Comment: I don't think the problem is minSdk value, but something else. Please provide more focus on your question adding more useful information about any error you see or the step you're following to start the emulator.